# How to calculate the residue of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis

The residue of $f(z)=z\sin\frac{1}{1-z}$ at $z=1$. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearranging to get everything in terms of $(z-1)$ might help:

$$z\sin\frac{1}{1-z}=-((z-1)+1)\sin\frac{1}{z-1}=-(z-1)\sin\frac{1}{z-1}-\sin \frac{1}{z-1}.$$  You could use the beginning of the power series of $\sin$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Jonas. I am clear.